# Symfony 2.5 - IvoryCKEditorBundle fatal error (class not found)

Tags: php, symfony, ckeditor, bundle

I was trying to get installed the bundle `egeloen/IvoryCKEditorBundle` in my Symfony 2.5 but it's my first time installing a bundle and I need specific steps to make it, I don't understand in which files I have to put the code lines to get it installed, I write the code in the README file in appKernel, autoload.php and composer.json. It runs in a local host and I Use Xampp, my OS is Windows 7.
The error I got was:

> Fatal error: Class 'web\bundles\IvoryCKEditorBundle' not found in
> D:...\Source\app\AppKernel.php on line 19

Comment: Did you run `php app/console assets:install web` ?

Comment: No, I haven't. Where I have to run it?

Comment: Same way you use the `cache:clear` command, in the console. If you don't know how tell us more about your environment: local or server ? Which OS ? Using wamp or the such ? Don't hesitate to edit your post with such infos.